# How to mock requests.get inside Image.open

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-requests, mocking

In my code I am opening images from links using following code:

```
from PIL import Image
Image.open(requests.get(image_link, stream=True).raw)
```

Now I am mocking `requests.get` in my unit tests and I am using this:

```
mock_response = MagicMock()
mock_response.status_code = 200
mock_response.json.return_value = mock_data
```

But it is not working for images. I have no idea how to mock this image. I was trying to just put binary data instead of `mock_data` but it is not working and `Image.open` returns me that it can't find a file. Does someone know how to mock it?

Comment: `Image.open` expects path to the file, not the raw data.

Comment: But in my case I don't have any path. I am getting image from link. It also accepts more inpouts like `StringIO` but I was trying to open image as bytes and it doesn't work.